# Swift UIView.animateWithDuration and For-Loops

Tags: ios, swift, animation, for-loop

I have a group of UIImageViews that are stored in an array. I want to animate a certain amount of these ImageViews in the same way. Thus, I have been trying to use the following code:

```
var lowerViews: [UIImageView] = [imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4]

var startingIndex = 1;

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

     for index in startingIndex..< lowerViews.count {
         lowerViews[index].frame.origin.y += 100
     }

}, completion: nil)
```

However at this line:

```
for index in startingIndex..< lowerViews.count {
```

Xcode gives me the error:

> Expected '{' to start the body of each for-loop

However, I don't believe that this is really the issue. This seems to me that it is an arbitrary syntax error that Xcode gets because I am using the for-loop inside the 'animation' parameter. Since I am still learning a lot about Swift I do not know why this wouldn't work, and so if this assumption is correct, I would like to know why and how I can get around this.

If this is not the case, please let me know, because either way I need to get around the problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky error (note spaces around `..<`).

```
for index in startingIndex ..< lowerViews.count {
```

will work or

```
for index in startingIndex..<lowerViews.count {
```

will work but:

```
for index in startingIndex..< lowerViews.count {
```

won't work.

The reason for this is the fact that when `startingIndex..<` is used, then `..<` is considered to be a postfix (unary) operator (not an infix operator). Therefore the whole expression stops making sense and you start getting strange errors.

Also see [what are the rules for spaces in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301715/what-are-the-rules-for-spaces-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem