# Simple Int sum error

Tags: swift, sum

I am just starting out with Swift, coming from Objective-C. I have this line:

```
self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [IndexPath.init(row: (self.flights.count -1), section: 0)])
```

I get an error saying: `Expected ',' separator` after 'count'.

Why on earth can I not do a simple sum, the count -1? A little quirk of Swift I haven't yet learnt, or its too early in the morning...

Comment: When you put `-` before `1` without space Swift interprets `-` as prefix unary operator. And you got something like `self.flights.count (-1)`, which is not grammatically correct`

Comment: See [what are the rules for spaces in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301715/what-are-the-rules-for-spaces-in-swift).

Comment: I think you meant "Simple Int subtraction error"... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to Apple's "[Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html)" Documentation:

> The whitespace around an operator is used to determine whether an
>   operator is used as a prefix operator, a postfix operator, or a binary
>   operator. This behavior is summarized in the following rules:
>
> - If an operator has whitespace around both sides or around neither side, it is treated as a binary operator. As an example, the +++
>     operator in a+++b and a +++ b is treated as a binary operator.
> - If an operator has whitespace on the left side only, it is treated as a prefix unary operator. As an example, the +++ operator in a +++b
>     is treated as a prefix unary operator.
> - If an operator has whitespace on the right side only, it is treated as a postfix unary operator. As an example, the +++ operator in a+++ b
>     is treated as a postfix unary operator.
> - If an operator has no whitespace on the left but is followed immediately by a dot (.), it is treated as a postfix unary operator.
>     As an example, the +++ operator in a+++.b is treated as a postfix
>     unary operator (a+++ .b rather than a +++ .b).

***Note***: `++` and `--` has been removed from Swift 3. For more information, check [0004 Swift evolution proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md).

Means that the minus operator in `self.flights.count -1` treated as prefix unary operator (second rule).

To make it more clear, the compiler reads `self.flights.count -1` as: *self.flights.count, next to it there is a minus one*, but NOT a subtraction operation. By applying the second rule, the minus is a prefix unary operator for the `1`.

Obviously, you want the compiler to treat the minus operator as a binary operator, so what you should do is to add whitespace around both sides of the minus (applying the first rule):

```
self.collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath.init(row: (flights.count - 1), section: 0)])
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a space

```
self.collectionView?.insertItems(at: [IndexPath.init(row: (self.flights.count - 1), section: 0)])
```