# Swift: '==' is not a prefix unary operator

Tags: swift

I'm building a simple swift 3 application as I am learning it now, and I got this error `'==' is not a prefix unary operator`

This is my code

```
@IBAction func convertClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    if let result = tempEntry.text {
        if(result =="") {
            return
        } else {
            if let num = Double(result) {
                let output = num * (9/5) + 32
                ResultLabel.text = String(output)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the comma for?

Comment: This is how  Swift tries to fix it, the comma should not be in the original code

Comment: have you tried space after == ? if(result == "") {

Comment: What's the swift version ?

Comment: `if(result =="")` is supposed to be `if(result == "")`... spot the space after the `==` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add space after '=='.

Instead of :

```
if(result =="") {
```

try:

```
if(result == "") {
```

Comment: Can't wait to hear why -1 :)

Comment: expand answer explaining why space is needed as [answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31302667/6920962), for example.

Comment: That's why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/4687348

Comment: user28434 does lack of in depth information makes my answer incorrect? wrong? misleading?
@FelixSFD care to explain some more? This one is regarding off topic questions...

Comment: Space after = worked in my case