# Checking if values in 2 NSTextFields are positive integers in a single If statement

Tags: swift, macos

I have two textboxes. When the user clicks on a button, I need to check if the values entered into the textfields are positive integers.

I try to do this using the following statement:

```
if ((Int(txta.stringValue))! < 0 ||(Int(txtb.stringValue))! < 0)
{
            // Display error message
}
```

But it seems there is an issue with the `if` statement syntax.
`Expected ',' separator` is the error produced.

What I'm I doing wrong?

Please advise.

Comment: `Int(txta.stringValue) != nil && Int(txtb.stringValue) != nil`

Comment: Are you trying to limit the input text on your field to positive integers? Is zero also allowed? Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: 0 is not Allowed.I want the user to enter only positive  integers.Im checking this using the code above .

Comment: Are you aware that `(Int(txta.stringValue))!` *crashes* for non-integer input?

Comment: @MartinR No... I could not test the code.

Comment: Well, you could start with checking a *single* input field and make that work. But you know that the "forced-unwrap" operator `!` can cause a runtime exception?

Comment: @MartinR hmm okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems:

- Binary operators (such as `||`) must have whitespace on *both* sides
  (or on none), that's what causes the syntax error. (See [what are the rules for spaces in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301715/what-are-the-rules-for-spaces-in-swift).)
- `if (Int(txta.stringValue))! < 0` cannot be used to check for integer
  input because the forced unwrap  *crashes* at runtime if the string is
  not an integer.

`Int(txta.stringValue)` returns `nil` if the string is not an integer, so
a possible check for integer input would be

```
if Int(txta.stringValue) == nil || Int(txtb.stringValue) == nil {
    // display error message
}
```

But most probably you need the integer values themselves (in the case of valid input),
that's what *optional binding* is for 
(see also [When should I compare an optional value to nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717210/when-should-i-compare-an-optional-value-to-nil)):

```
if let a = Int(txta.stringValue), let b = Int(txtb.stringValue) {
    // Valid input, values are in `a` and `b` ...
} else {
    // display error message
}
```

Additional conditions can be added to check the valid range, e.g.

```
if let a = Int(txta.stringValue), let b = Int(txtb.stringValue), a > 0, b > 0 {
    // Valid positive input, values are in `a` and `b` ...
} else {
    // display error message
}
```

Or with `guard`:

```
guard let a = Int(txta.stringValue), let b = Int(txtb.stringValue), a > 0, b > 0 else {
    // display error message
    return
}
// Valid positive input, values are in `a` and `b` ...
```

Comment: Thanks ..will check and get back tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks,your solution works perfect.I will learn more about `guard` statements.

Comment: If I need to set a Boolean variable if the values are integers .. I can do like this .. I guess `guard .......... {
    // display error message
    return
} myvar=true`

Answer (score 0):

This is an ideal case for `Optional.map` and `Optional.flatMap`:

```
if (Int(textA.stringValue).map{ 0 <= $0 } ?? false) &&
   (Int(textB.stringValue).map{ 0 <= $0 } ?? false) {

}
```

To break it down:

1. `textA` is a `NSTextField`.
2. `textA.stringValue` is some non-optional `String` value
3. `Int(textA.stringValue)` converts the text field's non-optional string value into an `Int?` value (a.k.a. `Optional<Int>`). It's optional, since the conversion from `String` to `Int` can fail (when the string doesn't encode an integer)
4. `map{ 0 <= $0 }` is called on that `Int?`. This is `Optional.map`, not to be confused with more common `map` functions, like `Array.map`. If the optional has some value, then the provided closure is applied to it. Otherwise, the `nil` is propagated onwards. Thus, the result of `Int(textA.stringValue).map{ 0 <= $0 }` is `Bool?`, with three possible values:

   1. `true` (`Optional.some(true)`), meaning the text field encodes a positive (non-negative) integer.
   2. `false` (`Optional.some(false)`), meaning the text field encodes a negative integer.
   3. `nil` (`Optional.none`), meaning the text field doesn't encode an integer at all.
5. The *nil coalescing* operator is used (`??`), to merge the `nil` case into the `false` case. Thus, the result of `Int(textA.stringValue).map{ 0 <= $0 } ?? false` has 2 values:

   1. `true` meaning the text field encodes a positive integer.
   2. `false` meaning the text field encodes a negative integer, or doesn't encode a number at all. In either case, it doesn't encode a positive integer
6. The process is repeated for `textB`, and the two expressions are *and*ed together (`&&`)

Comment: @techno Hold on, there's a mistake, working on fixing it now

Comment: stringValue on OSX it is not optional

Comment: why not simply `if let valueA = Int(txta.stringValue),
        let valueB = Int(txtb.stringValue), valueA >  0 && valueB > 0`

Comment: @LeoDabus Totally possible, too. I would even prefer it, but that gets more complicated with more intermediate steps. E.g. on iOS where `UITextField.text` is Optional, or when there's a problem involving more conversions. You end up needing lots of non-descript but different names for the intermediate values

Comment: You  should always prefer readability. look at how you should do it at Martin’s answer

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm aware. I'm merely conveying an alternative that introduces people to the idea of mapping optionals.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155715/discussion-between-alexander-and-leo-dabus).

Comment: @Alexander you are over complicating such an easy task. I have already seen you posting to use map on optionals but thats definitely not the case.

Comment: @LeoDabus Read what I wrote in chat ^