# How to use conditional operator (? :) in swift4

Tags: swift

When I use conditional operator in Swift, like this:

`let foo = array.count < 0? 0 : array.count`

I got error:

> Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'

I know that `?` in swift is used to unwrap optional.

Should I use this operator in swift?

If I can, how?

Comment: add a space between the `0` and ? like so: `< 0 ?`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301715/what-are-the-rules-for-spaces-in-swift

Comment: In swift sometimes a space can cause problem, cannot write randomly like obj-c

Comment: How would you expect to an array to have less than 0 elements? Couldn't you find a better example than that?

Comment: As @LeoDabus says, this is somewhat nonsensical, since `array.count` will never be less than 0. However, for cases where a value legitimately can be negative and you want to bound it, the `max` function is a better choice, i.e.: `let foo = max(somePossibleNegative, 0)`

Comment: Sorry, this is just a sample, I will not do it in my code, thx! @LeoDabus

Comment: It works, thx! @Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

spacing should be either

```
let foo = array.count < 0 ? 0 : array.count
```

or

```
let foo = array.count<0 ? 0:array.count
```