# Custom Range Operators - Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, range, operators, operator-precedence, infix-operator

## Custom Range Operators

### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3

I am looking to make two custom range operators: `<..`, `<.<`

---

### 1. `<..`

- This operator will be sort of the inverse of the `..<` range operator.

#### My Attempt:

```swift
infix operator <.. : RangeFormationPrecedence

public func <.. (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Range {
    return lhs - 1 ... rhs
}
```

#### Errors:

[image: 1. Custom Range Operator Error]

***Note:*** I also get about an additional 22 compile time errors surrounding the actual declaration of the custom operator (`<..`) itself.

#### Ideal Usage:

```swift
for i in 1<..9 {
    print(i, terminator: " ")
}

// Prints "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

---

### 2. `<.<`

- I want to make sort of a combination of my previous custom range operator. `<..` and `..<`

#### My Attempt:

```swift
infix operator <.< : RangeFormationPrecedence

public func <.< (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Range {
    return lhs - 1 ..< rhs
}
```

#### Errors:

[image: 2. Custom Range Operator Error]

***Note:*** I also get about an additional 22 compile time errors surrounding the actual declaration of the custom operator (`<.<`) itself.

#### Ideal Usage:

```swift
for i in 1<.<10 {
    print(i, terminator: " ")
}

// Prints "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

---

**How can I accomplish this?**

**Also, what type of `Range` should I be returning?**

**Lastly, are there any preconditions that need to be added to the custom range operators themselves to ensure safety?**

---

### Update

I decided to create two operators (1x postfix, 1x infix) to accomplish one of these goals:

```swift
postfix operator <

public postfix func < <T: Numeric>(n: T) -> T { return n - 1 }


infix operator .< : RangeFormationPrecedence

public func .< <T: Numeric>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> CountableRange<T> {
    return lhs ..< rhs
}
```

**Then I can do:**

```
for i in 1<.<10 {
    print(I, terminator: " ")
}

//Prints "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
```

***Caveat:*** I cannot have a space between the numbers and the operators (i.e. `1 <.< 10`)

---

Comment: You should be increasing the index instead of subtracting 1

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Just updated the question @BallpointBen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<..` and `<.<` are not valid identifiers for operators. You'll find the
details in [Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID418) in the Swift language reference.

Mimicking the declaration of the existing

```
extension Strideable where Self.Stride : SignedInteger {
    public static func ... (minimum: Self, maximum: Self) -> CountableClosedRange<Self>
}
```

operator, your first custom operator can be implemented as

```
infix operator <!! : RangeFormationPrecedence

extension Strideable where Self.Stride : SignedInteger {
    public static func <!! (minimum: Self, maximum: Self) -> CountableClosedRange<Self> {
        return minimum.advanced(by: -1) ... maximum
    }
}
```

Example:

```
for i in 1<!!9 { print(i, terminator: " ") }
// 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The second operator can be implemented in a similar fashion, using
`CountableRange` instead of `CountableClosedRange`.

Comment: Why would I make an extension rather than an operator?

Comment: @NoahWilder:  All operators are functions. The question is: why an extension method and not a free function? I just looked up how `...` is defined. You can also define a free function `public func <!! <T: Strideable> (minimum: T, maximum: T) -> CountableClosedRange<T> where T.Stride: SignedInteger` – I don't think that it makes a difference.

Comment: I just though of another solution; what do you think? Also, do you have any idea how to make it so I can indeed have a space? @MartinR

Comment: @NoahWilder: There are also rules for spaces around operators, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301715/what-are-the-rules-for-spaces-in-swift. That's why `for i in 1 <.< 10` does not compile.

Comment: Don't mean to push @MartinR, but do you have any suggestions or workarounds to do something of the likes of what I would like to do?

Comment: @NoahWilder: I have tried to answer your (initial) question.  `<!!` was just an example to demonstrate how the operator can be defined .There are a lot of allowed Unicode characters which you can choose from. – Defining two operators for that purpose (where `.<` is just an alias for `..<`) is confusing in my opinion, and has “unexpected“ behavior with respect to spacing, as you noticed.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR